# How do I search reviews on information in custom ratings fields using Solspace Rating and paginate results?

Tags: solspace, search, pagination, solspace-rating

I am using Solspace Rating to allow users to review and rate entries from several different channels. I have set up custom rating fields in the Rating module to store different rating criteria for the different channels, using up to a dozen different custom fields for reviews in one channel.

I would like to allow users to search for reviews based on different criteria stored in the custom fields. The Rating module has no facility for doing this so I am having to work out my own way.

So far I am able to build a custom SQL query, based on POSTed form field data, to use the EE Query module to successfully get the particular results I am after. However, I have not been able to find a way of paginating the results as the data from the form fields is lost when you click on the link to view the second page of results.

Has anyone else come across this problem with the Rating module before? If so, how have you managed to implement search for reviews, based on information that is only stored in the Rating custom fields and not in the channel entries that have been reviewed?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this would be an issue with anything using POST variables in the EE query module and using pagination, not just with the Rating module. What if the search term was in the URL as a regular segment and you used that in the EE module? eg. http://mysite.com/rating/search/keyword/**great**, then

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT * FROM exp_rating WHERE my_review_field LIKE '%{segment_4}%'"}
```

Unfortunately Rating does not have a search feature built-in. I recommend submitting this as a Feature Request under the specific add-on category. It'll also give other users the option to vote up the feature request, and help us prioritize features to add in upcoming versions of this add-on.
http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions

Comment: I've added a feature request as suggested so if anyone else would like this feature, please vote for it! I'll look into the feasibility of using segments to store keywords.